# How to get the absolute position of the glContext in JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I was trying to translate the OpenGL context to a camera position so I could rotate the scene - however in order to put the context back at [0, 0, 0] I need to know the current position that the OpenGL context is in, in absolute co-ordinates(So I can subtract it)

Is there a way to do it using `(GL2).getContext()`? (Where GL2 is an instance of GL2)

[JOGL Version Information](https://pastebin.com/mzXTgZeA)

If I am phrasing this wrong or need to provide more information I apologise - still getting used to SO

Comment: The camera position is the translation of the inverse view matrix.

Comment: Rabbid76 what? I'm new to OGL and I dont know what you mean. It is my own camera class not the openGL one

Comment: Of course you have "your own" camera. OpenGL has nothing like a camera. Even an [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) has nothing to do with the orientation respectively look at the scene. The point of view is defined by the view matrix (your view matrix) and the translation of the inverse view matrix is the position of the "camera".

Comment: @Rabbid76 I still dont understand what you mean by 'View Matrix'...

Comment: The view matrix is that matrix that transforms the scene from world space to view space. You are missing fundamentals. Probably you should learn some basics (e.g. [Camera](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera)) before you go ahead.

Comment: @Rabbid76 cheers man - I honestly dont understand anything on that webpage but I'll give it a shot